# Jboss 7 firebird connection

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, firebird, jaybird

I'm having trouble connectiong to Firebird database (jaybird driver) from JBoss 7.1.0 CR1

This is the log:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.firebirdsql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:/tiranDS]
```

This is standalone.xml

This is my standalone.xml [some parts are changed, like ...(some_path)...]

```
...

  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/tiranDS" pool-name="TiranPool" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>
                        jdbc:firebirdsql:serversp/3050:C:\Program Files\...(some_path)...\tiran.gdb
                    </connection-url>
                    <driver>
                        firebirdsql
                    </driver>
                    <pool>
                        <prefill>
                            false
                        </prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>
                            false
                        </use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>
                            FailingConnectionOnly
                        </flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>
                            username
                        </user-name>
                        <password>
                            pass
                        </password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                   <driver name="firebirdsql" module="org.firebirdsql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>
                            org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
                        </xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
...
```

module.xml looks like this (all .jars mentioned in module.xml are in ...\jboss-as-7.1.0.CR1b\modules\org\firebirdsql\main folder)

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.firebirdsql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="jaybird-full-2.1.6.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jaybird-pool-2.1.6.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="log4j-1.2.13.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jboss-javaee.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jmxri.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jmxtools.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="sax2.jar"/>

        <resource-root path="commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="junit-3.8.1.jar"/>

    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.activation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.soap.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.common-core"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="javax.mail.api"/>


        <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>               
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j"/>
        <module name="org.apache.james.mime4j"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.codec"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.io"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.lang"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
        <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents"/>
        <module name="org.apache.xalan"/>
        <module name="org.apache.xerces"/>
        <module name="org.w3c.css.sac"/>
        <module name="net.sourceforge.cssparser"/>
        <module name="net.sourceforge.nekohtml"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Whati is wrong here?

---

Application with this driver class worked on JBoss 5, but I've tried both classes `org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver` and `org.firebirdsql.pool.FBConnectionPoolDataSource` still no change.

Also, I've tried putting jaybird-2.1.6.jar instead of jaybird-full-2.1.6.jar but still the error is the same.

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.firebirdsql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:/tiranDS]
```

Although I'm sure that all that you said Mark is true, it seems like the problem before all this mentioned above is that I'm missing some dependencies in module.xml but I do not know wich.

Answer (score 2):

The `org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver` is not an xa-datasource-class. This element requires the name of the `javax.sql.XADataSource` implementation in Jaybird, not the `java.sql.Driver` implementation.

In Jaybird 2.2 and higher, the `XADataSource` implementation is `org.firebirdsql.ds.FBXADataSource`.

The `XADataSource` implementation in Jaybird 2.1.6 and earlier is `org.firebirdsql.pool.FBConnectionPoolDataSource` (see also http://web.firebirdsql.org/devel/doc/jaybird/pdf/jaybird_manual.pdf ); this class was deprecated in Jaybird 2.2 and removed in Jaybird 3.

As far as I know JBoss actually includes an example to use Firebird. (but that might have been an earlier version).

BTW: When using from an application server you should not use the jaybird-full-2.1.6.jar file, but jaybird-2.1.6.jar (as the former includes some (older) JavaEE interfaces that are already included in JBoss)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little late, the point is simply that Firebird is not really JDBC 4 so you have to add the driver class yourself to the configuration like this:

```
<driver name="firebirdsql" module="org.firebirdsql">
  <driver-class>org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</driver-class>
  <xa-datasource-class>org.firebirdsql.pool.FBConnectionPoolDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

That should solve your problem

Comment: Jaybird 2.2 and higher are JDBC 4 compliant.